# SQL Honor Roll, 3 Quarters per Line

Tags: sql

This sql is for a school with quartly honor roll.  The office would like a report which prints out only students with High Honors, and Honors then calculate if the student has all three quarters with High Honors, or Honors to qualify for an Honors breakfast.  It should look like this

```
StudentName | Q1    | Q2   | Q3
Name        Honor | High | Honor Honor
```

I currently have the sql set to one studentID; 6087, and this is the outcome:
[image]

I'm not sure why the group by setting is not providing 1 line of output per student. Does this require a subquery in the SELECT statement to produce the results?

```
SELECT
s1.DCID, hr1.levelvalue, hr1.storecode

FROM students s1 JOIN honorroll hr1 ON s1.id=hr1.studentid
WHERE hr1.yearid = 27
AND s1.id = 6087
GROUP BY s1.DCID, hr1.levelvalue, hr1.storecode
ORDER BY  s1.dcid, hr1.storecode;
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and what's your dbms?

Comment: The more grouping columns the more rows you'll get. Each combination of the three values produces its own group for output.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.id, min(s.Name),
    min(case when hr.Column3 = `Q1` then hr.Column2 end) Q1, ...
FROM students s INNER JOIN honorroll hr ON s.id = hr.studentid
WHERE hr.Column3 in ('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3') -- possibly redundant
    and hr.Column2 in ('Honors', 'High Honors')
GROUP BY s.id
HAVING count(distinct hr.Column3) = 3
```

Comment: I'm not sure if levelvalue and storecode correspond to column3 and column2. Hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

That worked perfectly.  The final code to sort by s.lastname:

```
SELECT
s.DCID,
min(s.lastfirst), 
min(Case WHEN hr.storecode='Q1' THEN hr.levelvalue END) Q1,
min(Case WHEN hr.storecode='Q2' THEN hr.levelvalue END) Q2,
min(Case WHEN hr.storecode='Q3' THEN hr.levelvalue END) Q3

FROM students s INNER JOIN honorroll hr ON s.id=hr.studentid
WHERE s.enroll_status=0 AND s.schoolid=~(curschoolid)
AND hr.yearid = 27
AND hr.storecode IN ('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3')
AND hr.levelvalue in ('High Honors', 'Honors')
GROUP BY s.DCID, s.lastfirst
HAVING count(hr.levelvalue) = 3
ORDER BY min(s.lastfirst);
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q596z.png)

Thank you very much!
Liz